# Using Jquery off().on() or just on()

Tags: jquery

I know that we can attach events with the jQuery `on()` function and remove them again with `off()`.

In an existing project I do sometimes come across code similar to this:

```
$("#SomeId").off("click").on("click");
```

or sometimes when using namespacing similar to this:

```
$("#SomeId").off("click.namespace").on("click.namespace");
```

<strike>As far as I know you can only attach a single event to a specific namespace of the event.</strike>

For example if I simply do `on("click")` it will attach my specified function, <strike>overwriting the current function assigned</strike>, adding to the "click" event.

If I do `on("click.namespace")` it will attach my specified function <strike>overwriting the current function assigned</strike>, adding to the `click.namespace`.

What is the point removing any events by chaining an `off("click")` to the `on("click)` if `on()` already replaces any functions assigned to the specified event/event.namespace?

Is it redundant syntax in our code or is there a reason for it which I have missed?

**Edit - Thank you `kapa`**
I feel a bit silly now, I corrected my faulty knowledge above. Executing `on("click.namespace1")` several times I observed now that the `data("events")` object kept adding to the click event array.

I think that answers my own question there. That is why one would use `off("event.namespace")` to ensure nothing else is attached to that exact event/event.namespace.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Actually you can attach multiple event handlers to the same event, not just one. Even when namespaces are used. Check out [this quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gEupv/).

Actually, one advantage of namespaces is that you can mark a group of event handlers, and easily remove them later to avoid attaching them several times. This is what this line does:

```
$("#SomeId").off("click.namespace").on("click.namespace");
```

Comment: I edited my question with the new findings based on your feedback. I feel a bit silly I never noticed that before when observing the `data("events")` object. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: same as above fiddle added some comments Hope it will be helpful for some one https://jsfiddle.net/AnuragKumar/d4j30k1q/

Comment: thank me later
https://www.andismith.com/blogs/2013/02/jquery-on-and-off-namespacing/

Answer (score 3):

#### You may want to try `.one('click.namspace')` instead of `.on('click.namespace')`.

```
$('p')
  .off('click.namespace', clickCB)
  .one('click.namespace', clickCB); // note the .one() here
```

This way you ensure that the click is not called more than **once**, otherwise, the `.on(...)` will only keep adding `click-event-handlers (clickCBs)` to the `click.namespace` event on `p` element and will be called multiple times before the `.off()` is triggered.

Good Luck...

Comment: Will this still keep adding the event handlers?
`$("#SomeId").off("click.namespace").on("click.namespace"); `

Comment: i think that will clear them before adding new

Comment: @MR_AMDEV, I can't recall the context where this solution helped me.  If I recall; I'll add a code-snippet for the same.  Thanks :)

Comment: @MR_AMDEV It is important to note that it does not remove the event before adding new, but rather removes the event AFTER it has been executed

Answer (score 0):

If there is an existing hander (since you may have more than one, in this case, they will chain), and it calls [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), then your hander will not be called. Writing the code as above will avoid this issue.