# How to use the way of jQuery .on() and .off() in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Am currently working on angular 2 web application. Actually whenever i'm double click the submit button.Action takes place two time. So I want to implement the [Jquery .on() .of() method](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/).

I know the logic. **We can disable/enable the button with the flag while click the submit button**.

```
clickFunction()
{
isdisabled=false;// disable button
if(isclicked)
//service call back  & clear the inputs
isdisabled = true;//enable button
}
```

But I don't want do it manually. So any idea about to use the way of [jQuery .on() and .off()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979865/using-jquery-off-on-or-just-on) in **angular 2**??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2 Please refer this, you might get some idea.

Comment: I don't like to use Jquery code. I want to know if possible to use  the exact event of Jqery on() and off() in angular 2

Comment: This will lead you to some conclusion without jquery
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121134/how-to-deal-with-double-submit-in-angular2

Comment: What is it that you actually want? You say "I don't want to do it manually", what does that mean? You are looking for some module that do it for you?

Comment: I think the problem here is that Angular is a much more asynchronous model than jQuery, so simply disabling a button while you are processing the click is probably not going to be sufficient in most cases as you will want to kick off some event emitter or something and wait until that has completed before you re-enable the button. Perhaps using `Rx.Observable.debounce()` would help you: instead of disabling the button during the event just ignore any duplicate clicks that come too soon after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "You don't want to do it manually". Perhaps you're looking for the `[disabled]` attribute that you can attach to your HTML button with a condition.

Also, note that we disable the button when our service return the response. If you put it outside the `subscribe()` method then it might enable the button too quickly.

### HTML

```
<button (click)="doAction()" [disabled]="disabled">Click</button>
```

### JS

```
doAction() {
    disabled = true;
    this.myService.doServiceAction()
        .subscribe(result => {
            disabled = false
        })
}
```

Comment: Actually what am expecting is need to switch on/off the current event. does make sense?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this for on/off (enabling/disabling) button.

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("buttonId")).disabled = !(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("buttonId")).disabled;
```

Comment: Actually am forget `document.getElementById` the. Am working with angular 2 . not javascript

Comment: you can use the `getElementById` in angular 2 (typescript) too. additionally, you have to cast it to `HTMLInputElement` to access its native properties and that is what i did..

Comment: But why I need it? angular  is support for two way binding. then why I need implement this? I have a pure idea about it  which am explain in my question. but I want to switch off/on the click event

Comment: What exactly is your question about implementation of the switch property in jQuery? As I see it, do you want to use only jQuery for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can you RxJs with angular2 or 4. Please checkout eventsubscriber.

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

var subscription = source.subscribe(function (e) {
  result.innerHTML = e.clientX + ', ' + e.clientY;
});
```

Comment: What is this? is it have any relation from my question?

Answer (score -2):

Using ng-disabled should work for your need. Usually it takes less than 1-2 milliseconds for $eval and $apply methods to execute.

Edited:

Use some thing like this to emit an event.

```
<button ng-click="clicked()">button<>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.clicked() = function() {
   $scope.emit('clicked-once');
}



 $scope.on('clicked-once', function(event) {
  // do something here 
 })
```

Keep a track of clicks with flag.

Comment: I know that logic. But I want do it with using event emitter as JQuery on off event

Comment: The question isn't about AngularJs.